# Updating migration rails -mysqlite problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration

I have updated my user migration changing the column "user" with "username" and now when running

```
User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
```

server outputs

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL ORDER BY user LIMIT 1
```

Why it still trying ordering by "user" ??

thanks.

UPDATE:

here's user table

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username",                                                         :null => false
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "hashed_password",                                                  :null => false
    t.string   "salt",                                                             :null => false
    t.string   "mail",                                                             :null => false
    t.integer  "login_count",                   :default => 0
    t.datetime "last_login",                    :default => '2011-06-23 08:59:41'
    t.datetime "last_request_at",               :default => '2011-06-23 08:59:41'
    t.string   "user_type",                     :default => "ruolo da definire"
    t.integer  "ammonizioni",                   :default => 0
    t.integer  "numero_segnalazioni_accettate", :default => 0
    t.integer  "numero_segnalazioni_risolte",   :default => 0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

UPDATE 2: if it helps ... I'm using cancan and the error come from the method "current_user" on application controller:

```
def current_user
  @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
end
```

---

**The solution of the problem has reveaved a new one:**

```
  def User.authenticate(user, password)
    if user = find_by_username(user)
      if user.hashed_password == encrypt_password(password, user.salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end
```

This worked well until I changed the migration. THe error for the first problem is repeated:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL ORDER BY user LIMIT 1
```

How should I modify this?

```
if user = User.find_by_username(user)
```

Answering to Mike:

- yes `session[:user_id]` is null because I'm not logged in
- your solution, for the second problem, produce the same error!

Comment: Can you verify with an SQLite viewer that the migration indeed renamed the column to 'username'?

Comment: You can also check your `schema.rb` file for Roy's suggestion as well as doing `rake db:migrate:status` if you're in Rails 3.

Comment: In schema.rb column is "user". What can I do for changing it? Manually didn't work!

Comment: Can you update your post with your schema for the User table please?

Comment: SORRY, on schema.rb column is "username" ... my fault. By the way, now I update my post

Comment: If you changed an **existing** migration file, be sure to rollback it with `rake db:rollback` and migrate it again.

Comment: I think `User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])` is returning 'NULL'.  Can you check this please - your can try `raise User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).to_yaml` - it would be nil if you're not logged in.

Comment: Maybe I don't get your help ...

Comment: I have done another update, maybe helps

Comment: Please paste the output of `raise User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]).to_yaml`

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL ORDER BY user LIMIT 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
 def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
 end
```

or alternatively,

```
 def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
 end
```

The important point to note is that I'm checking to see that `session[:user_id]` is not null.  If you look at your SQL error `...WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL ...` it **is** indeed null.

**Update**

> yes session[:user_id] is null because I'm not logged in

That's why I ended with `if session[:user_id]` to ensure such a session exists in the first place.

#### Update #2

To prove that `.find_by_username(user.username)` works and simply passing in `user` I just tried a test

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :003 > User.find_by_name(User.all.last)
 => nil
```

Of course, as expected, `User.find_by_name(User.all.last.name)` works :)

Comment: btw ... I have the same problem on this line:

 if user = find_by_username(user) [...]

Comment: You can't do that.  `find_by_*` is a method that needs to be called on a model in question.  You can do `User.find_by_username("Jimmy Page")` - you can't pass a `user` object there.

Comment: I suggest you [read up on this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3).

Comment: that's not the entire object, but the name of the user passed from the function authenticate (session_controller): User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

Comment: @Massimo, go back and look at your definition.  `user` there is not the same as `user.username`.  Try it and you'll see.

Comment: and to make matters worse you're doing `if user = User.find_by_username(user)` instead of `if a == b` for comparison!

Comment: user.username tells me that is not existing a method for a nill class. "user" is a variable that could be named "teapot".

Concerning "if user = User.find_by_username(user)": it worked (before migrate changhes) and is right! (... that code from "agile web development with rails")

Comment: BTW, `u = User.last; u.object_id => 2201844780` so yes, `user` is an object.

Comment: @Massimo, you've misunderstood me.  If you were to call your definition as `User.authenticate("Bob", "password")`, then sure you can leave it in as `user` - however, this is not how I'd do it.  Instead I'd be doing `User.authenticate(@user, @user.password)`.

Comment: Here's one last update based on your context. Make it `if user == User.find_by_username(user).username`, as `User.find_by_username(user)` would return the user.  Therefore, you can further shorten this to `if user && User.find_by_username(user)`.  Honestly, I do not like the name you have chosen for the local var.  If I took your approach, I'd instead perform `if username && User.find_by_username!(username)` or `if username && User.where(:username => username)`; the first `username` is there to check that it's not `nil` and `.find_by_username!` so that it'll raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.